# Can we tell from periodic table that which materials are ferromagnetic?

Tags: electromagnetism, chemical-compounds

I want to know that because I want to see whether ferromagnetic materials relate to the number of outer most electrons. If there is no direct relationship, could you please give me a list of the materials that are ferromagnetic? Thanks

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism#Ferromagnetic_materials. The only ferromagnetic elements in the main part of the table are iron, cobalt, and nickel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ferromagnetism is the basic mechanism by which certain materials (such as iron) form permanent magnets, or are attracted to magnets.

It is caused due to unpaired electrons alignment in same spin moment to create high value of magnetism. We cannot comment on spin moments of the electrons(unpaired) just by seeing , so i think it's not possible.